# Hyperlink gets disabled when reinitializing JQuery DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, datatable

The following code samples demonstrates how I initialize a jQuery Datatable with HTML, knockout and typescript

HTML:

```
<table id="coursemoment-info-table"  class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr >
        // headers
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- ko foreach: selectedCourseMoment().courseApplications -->
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a data-bind="{text: ssn, attr:{ href: '/Medlem/'  + ssn} }"></a>
            </td>
            <td data-bind="text:name + ' ' + surname"></td>
            .
            .   
            .
        </tr>
        <!-- /ko-->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Typescript:

```
private initCourseMomentInformationDataTable(): void {
    $("#coursemoment-info-table").DataTable({
        pageLength: 5,
        order: [1, 'desc'],
        language: {
            url: "/Assets/js/jquery-datatable-swedish.json"
        }
    });
}
```

I have had some problems with reinitializing the table, but I managed to handle it with first clearing the datatable, and then adding rows to the datatable and redraw it.

```
 if (this.tableInitiliazed) {

                $("#coursemoment-info-table").DataTable().clear().draw();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.courseApplications.length; i++) {
                    var application = data.courseApplications[i];
                    $("#coursemoment-info-table").DataTable().row.add(
                        [
                            application.ssn,
                            // blah blah yada yada

                        ]).draw();
                }
```

This does indeed reinitiliaze the datatable, but it does not put a hyperlink to the first column as it does when initializing the table. All the other table settings are correct, such as language and pagelength.

Since I add one row at a time, with the multiple columns I do not know how to set column settings for "applications.ssn" directly. I have tried to initialize the datatable in the viewmodel with typescript but I get the same problem.

Any ideas how to reinitialize and put a hyperlink setting for a specific column?

Comment: I know nothing about datable, I'm sorry, but in Knockout you need to update a ViewModel that has observables, and Knockout will show its updated values.  Here is an example:  https://datatables.net/dev/knockout/, hope this helps.

Comment: Hi,  the viewmodel gets updated and the table gets the correct data. It is just that the column where the hyperlinks should be put does not work when reinitializing the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use Datatables render to create your link.  so here is a custom data binder for data table that  uses render to create the link.

here is the fiddle to see it in action.  http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/35823/

```
   ko.bindingHandlers.dataTable = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var value = valueAccessor(),
      rows =  ko.toJS(value);
      allBindings = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor()),
      $element = $(element);

   var table =  $element.DataTable( {
         data: rows,
          columns: [
            { data: "id" },
            { data: "firstName" },
            { data: "lastName" },
            { data: "phone" },
            {
               data: "ssn",
                "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
                return '<a href="/Medlem/'+data+'">' + data + '<a>';
             }
           }
        ]
    } );


    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
      $element.dataTable().fnDestroy();
    });

    value.subscribe(function(newValue) {
     rows = ko.toJS(newValue)
     console.log(rows);
       $element.find("tbody tr").remove();
       table.rows().remove().draw();

setTimeout(function(){    $.each(rows, function( index, row ) {
            table.row.add(row).draw()
        });
     }, 0);


    }, null);
  }
}
```